# UITextField set the Text after everything is loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift

alright, the title might be a bit misleading, but I wasn't sure how to properly describe it. But anyways, here we go:

I've got a `UIViewController` (within a `UITabBarController`) which contains a `UITextField`. When pushing this ViewController on to the Navigation Stack I've got to do some Work with the `UITextField`:

I put String inside the `UITextField` and process them (again, this all happens when the ViewController loads (currently inside the `viewDidLoad()` method)). In order to process them, I need to calculate the Rectangle which the String occupies inside the `UITextField`.

```
var pos1 = tagTextField.positionFromPosition(tagTextField.beginningOfDocument, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.Right, offset: 0)
var pos2 = tagTextField.positionFromPosition(tagTextField.endOfDocument, inDirection: UITextLayoutDirection.Right, offset:0)
var rectForButton = tagTextField.firstRectForRange(tagTextField.textRangeFromPosition(pos1, toPosition: pos2))
```

Exactly here is my problem. When doing this while the view is loaded, the tagTextField contains text, but does not show the text, therefore the rectForButton does not have any width.

My thoughts on this were, that I have to run this on a later point (I tried `viewWillAppear()`, `viewDidAppear()`, etc. but nothing worked).

Anybody any idea how to solve this? Basically to sum it up, I need a method which is called after everything concerning the UIViewController has happened.

Not sure if this of any significance, but I work with Swift and XCode 6 (the latest release of both)

Thanks

EDIT:

Apparently tagTextField.beginningOfDocument is nil, whereas tagTextField ist not nil. Anybody any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: Why dont you call the method to set text after you have done all the preparation inside the view controller itself. It is totally controllable, when you set the text to UITextField, so just do it after you have done all the setup.

Comment: yes, but when i set it inside viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, etc. the text still appear not immediately. I have no clue why.

Comment: Ok, Apparently I used the old beta without knowing it (I've installed the most recent version, but it openend the old beta, now I at least get an error that something is nil) Not sure though if this is the solution to my error

Answer (score 3):

Does your textfield comes from interface builder? You can try it in viewDidLayoutSubviews function.

Comment: I had different problem -UITextField.beginningOfDocument returns nil in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear but in viewDidLayoutSubviews all ok.

Thanks for the answer